# How I disable a specific HTML button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, in my HTML page I have 6 buttons having values 1,2,3,4,5 and the 6th button has the value "disable".
All I want to do is disable a specific button by clicking the "disable" button using jQuery. For example if I press the 3rd button and then immediately click the disable button, button 3 should be disabled and if i click 4th button and then immediately click the disable button then 4th button should be disabled.

thanx in advance.

Comment: where's your work? what have you done so far?

Comment: Present the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: welcome to SO . it will be better if you post some code supporting your question. It will help others to understand you better

Comment: you can use   $("button-id").attr("disabled", "disabled"); , on every button click initiate an event and on that event call function which is responsible for disabling button

Comment: it hears, like write me the code.... explain us, whats your problem and then we could help you.. whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

Buttons

```
<button class="btn">1</button>
<button class="btn">2</button>
<button class="btn">3</button>
<button class="btn">4</button>
<button class="btn">5</button>
<button class="btn">6</button>
<button class="dis">Disable</button>
```

And some jQuery

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('button').removeClass('active');
});

$('.dis').on('click', function() {
    $('.btn.active').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

and a

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yRkxY/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   // your code;
   $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="mybutton">1</button>
<button class="mybutton">2</button>
<button class="mybutton">3</button>
<button class="mybutton">4</button>
<button class="mybutton">5</button>
<button class="disable">Disable</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('.mybutton').on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('disableMe');
    });
    $('.disable').on('click',function(){
        $('.disableMe').prop('disabled',true);
    });    
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gVSPA/)

Comment: I just have the HTML: